# Itext : Property:FONT property with values of String type is deprecated

Tags: itext, itext7

Can you point to what I am doing wrong with the CSS that I am seeing a warning: The "Property.FONT" property with values of String type is deprecated, use String[] as property value type instead?

```
#insProv {
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,Serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#generalInfo {
    width: 260px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,Serif;
    margin-left: 475px;
}

#generalInfo td {
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,Serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

#generalInfoTitles {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#headerInfo {
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 465px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,Serif;
}

#headerInfo td {
    padding: 2px 2px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,Serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: Which versions of the itext artifacts do you use?

Answer (score 1):

`iText` used to have `setFont(String)` method, but it wasn't clear what was expected from its parameter: whether it's the font name or the font-family. Now the method is deprecated, and one is advised to set a list of Strings which represents font families (`ElementPropertyContainer#setFontFamily`).

It's strange that you get the message, because `pdfHTML` wraps the font-family in a `String[]`:

```
        List<String> fontFamilies = FontFamilySplitter.splitFontFamily(cssProps.get(CssConstants.FONT_FAMILY));
        element.setProperty(Property.FONT, fontFamilies.toArray(new String[fontFamilies.size()]));
```

Nevertheless, don't worry. `iText` logs a message, but wraps the font (in case it's a `String` in a `String[]`), so everything should be OK.

Comment: Its strange that I am completely using the itext libraries to convert html to pdf and there is no custom coding involved.I was wondering if there was any CSS change involved to fix this warning message. Guess not.

Comment: @nkare Could you then share your code and the complete html file which causes issues, so that I can have a look at it?